# Wordpress menu walker - removing class from submenu items

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a custom walker for my menu which adds correct classes to parent ul/li/a elements. But, on every submenu LI and A tag i would like to remove all the styling but i cant figure out how to do it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the code:

```
class CSS_Menu_Walker extends Walker {

    var $db_fields = array('parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id');

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='sub-menu'>\n";
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {

        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        /* Add active class */
        if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
            unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
        }

        /* Check for children */
        $children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
        if (!empty($children)) {
            $classes[] = 'nav-item-parent';
        }

        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="nav-item ' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($item->attr_title) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty($item->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target    ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($item->xfn       ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($item->url       ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' class="nav-link">';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

This is how the code should be outputed:

```
<li class="nav-item"> <!-- This is done properly -->
    <a href="#" class="nav-link "> <!-- This is done properly -->
        Top Level Link
    </a>
</li>   

<li class="nav-item nav-item-parent"><!-- This is done properly -->
    <a href="#" class="nav-link "> <!-- This is done properly -->
        Top Level Link
    </a>    

    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <!-- LI and A get css classes from their parents (aka, nav-item and nav-link) and i dont need any classes on them -->
        <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
    </ul>       
</li>
```

Comment: Please post your Nav css portion

Comment: @ShahGhafoori updated

Answer (score 0):

Using only CSS, you can target the element using its parent's class:

**Example:**

```
.nav-item ul li{
  //Your css declarations
}

.nav-item ul li a{
  //Your css declarations
}
```

Inspect the element and see what properties it gets from its parents.

For example if it gets padding of 15px from the parent, you can force to change the value:

```
.nav-item ul li a{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes, i know about that part and i have changed it i just tough there could be a "cleaner" solution that removes all of the classes via walker. but definitely thanks in anycase for your help!